# Failed an audit, what's my recourse?

Tags: discussion

I failed the following [low quality review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13107923):

[image]

I was told in a group that I should post this here for futher review (And to possibly remove this question from the audit review).

The page linked appeared to be an on topic domain, and the user in question (As far as I could tell), had no link to that site (So not spam). The answer did make an attempt to answer the question, and I feel like I shouldn't have failed this audit. What's my recourse in this case?

Comment: Actually I got that exact audit question before too and skipped it [because I was not _really_ sure]… But IMO, it indeed is very low quality. The author did not provide canonical information (statement from google? trustworthy news site?); he just throws out some statement and advertises another page by only posting a link to it. [which is not an official site or something]

Answer (score 4):

That answer was flagged as spam by six members of the community, and it was destroyed as such. That turned it into an audit case.

It was the only post by a new account, promoting an SEO optimization tool. The tool itself is free, but it seems like it might be advertising for a company's SEO services. That certainly looks a little shady to me, and spammers often write posts targeting off topic questions.

I don't think I'd approve that in review, and if six members of the site all flagged this as spam that seems like a pretty strong signal.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still a bit disappointed at the result, and hope it's removed from the audit review in the future (The comment about him skipping it would make me believe it's not a simple yes/no), and the socv review room was semi divided.

Comment: @FrankerZ I find it ironic that you were one of the six that originally flagged the post for spam. Yet the same post presented to you as an audit you argue that it's not spam? A little bit of consistency would go a long way here :)

Comment: @JonClements if there were six spam flags, why isn't the content hidden then? Was the last flag raised by  a mod?

Comment: @rene bah... posting without sufficient coffee... 4 spam flags/2 VLQ

Comment: @JonClements Yeah, I need to look more carefully when things get posted into the SCVR room. If someone posts, I usually agree with them for the most part (Doing a quick review), but when I do the actual reviews on the site, I usually do a bit more digging (Look into the website, look for the posters affiliation on the site, etc...). Clearly I need to review things more carefully in the future. I do believe though, that this post didn't deserve the spam flags.